# Cookies are not stored using ngCookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.0, I try use [`$cookies`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies). I also tried use example codes from documentation but it didn't work an I'm getting `put() is not a function`.

This is `LoginController` which should save token to cookie after successfull login.

```
.success(function (response) {
   $cookies["token"] = response.value.token;
   $log.info("Token: " + $cookies["token"]);
});
```

I'm getting proper value in console, but if i go to another page and try to get that value from cookie i'm getting `undefined` instead.

Reading cookie in `MainController`

```
 $log.info('New token:' + $cookies["token"]);
```

I checked in browser settings, and there aren't any cookie from localhost (I checked Safari and Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to see if the cookie is actually being set?
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

If at one point you set the flag "httpOnly" when setting the cookie, you cookie is indeed getting set, however you will not be able to read it from your client side javascript. You can set it, overwrite it, but you will not be able to read it unless you are reading the cookie header from the server side. Which actually is pretty cool when it comes to beefing up security a bit... but can be a real headache if you didn't realize the implications of setting that flag in the first place.

If you can see the cookie in your browser's settings, but cannot print it to the console without getting "undefined"... then simply delete it and reset it without the "httpOnly" flag.

Answer (score 0):

$cookies exposes methods you need to use. You don't set the properties on the $cookies object.

For example:

```
$cookies.put('keyHere', 'valueHere'); // set
$cookies.get('keyHere'); // get
$cookies.putObject('key2Here', {val: "etc"}); // set
$cookies.getObject('key2Here'); // get
```

So in your case, assuming the token is a string, your success function would do the following:

```
function (response) {
   $cookies.put("token", response.value.token);
}
```

You might have been reading older documentation, because the `$cookies` functionality changed after angular version 1.3. But the way I mentioned is how it should work for you, since you are using angular 1.5. [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Comment: `Error: $cookies.put is not a function. (In '$cookies.put("token", response.value.token)', '$cookies.put' is undefined)`

 I'm using "angular-cookies": "1.5.0"

Comment: Are you sure you are using angular 1.5 and an equivalent version of ngCookies? I use these methods in my app and they work fine - they come straight from the official documentation. You have to have a version mismatch going on or something. Can you set a breakpoint in your script and inspect the $cookies object to see what properties it has?

Comment: This is what I see: http://imgur.com/a/TRPPy      It seems like you reassigned $cookies to something else, or are using some other cookie library.   You included the 'ngCookies' in your module dependency list, and then injected $cookies into your controller, and then you used it in the code above right? Did you change it somewhere else or something? I don't even see that code you're seeing in the angular-cookies script.

Comment: [Here is what angular-cookies.js looks like, for reference](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies/blob/master/angular-cookies.js)

Comment: Now I moved up `log.info($cookies)'  http://pastebin.com/mEMhg8gr 
I'm using purchased bootstrap template with base angular app.

Comment: But `$cookies` object exist only in angular-cookie and my controller http://take.ms/OufnE

Comment: Wherever you first declared angular.module('oneday'), you need to have 'ngCookies' in your dependency list. i.e. `angular.module('oneday', ['ngCookies', 'etc', 'etc', 'etc'])`

Comment: Yup, I've it. I've `app.core` and there is dependency list http://pastebin.com/04wNhVHX . And `oneday` module has `app.core` in dependency list. Other dependencies works, so ngCookies should work too

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to explicitly state it as a dependency if it's already being used in a submodule, but it couldn't hurt to try. All I know is that you have a reference to the wrong $cookies object in the code in your main post.